# Use two different y-axis names with e_grid()

Tags: r, echarts4r

I want to have two different y-axis labels for two separate y-axes using `echarts4r::e_grid()`.

Here is the sample data taken from the example [here](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/grid.html#grid):

```r
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:20, 
  w = runif(20, 1, 100),
  z = runif(20, 25, 75)
)
```

Adding `name = "w"` works:

```r
df |> 
  e_charts(x) |> 
  e_line(w) |> 
  e_line(z, x_index = 1, y_index = 1) |> 
  e_grid(height = "35%") |> 
  e_grid(height = "35%", top = "50%") |> 
  e_y_axis(gridIndex = 1, name = "w") |>
  e_x_axis(gridIndex = 1)
```

[image: first-name-works]

I tried adding another `e_y_axis()` and specifying `gridIndex = 0`, but this results in a blank white plot.

```r
df |> 
  e_charts(x) |> 
  e_line(w, x_index = 0, y_index = 0) |> 
  e_line(z, x_index = 1, y_index = 1) |> 
  e_grid(height = "35%") |> 
  e_grid(height = "35%", top = "50%") |> 
  e_y_axis(gridIndex = 1, name = "w") |>
  e_y_axis(gridIndex = 0, name = "z") |>
  e_x_axis(gridIndex = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes these interactive charting libraries and their documentation drive me crazy. (; Using `e_y_axis(index = 1, name = "z")` with the `index` argument seems to work:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:20, 
  w = runif(20, 1, 100),
  z = runif(20, 25, 75)
)

library(echarts4r)
  
df |> 
  e_charts(x) |> 
  e_line(w) |> 
  e_line(z, x_index = 1, y_index = 1) |> 
  e_grid(height = "35%") |> 
  e_grid(height = "35%", top = "50%") |> 
  e_y_axis(gridIndex = 1, name = "w") |>
  e_y_axis(index = 1, name = "z") |>
  e_x_axis(gridIndex = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know _why_ this works? I'm struggling to make sense of the [documentation](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/grid.html).

Comment: Not really. This was more a trial and error approach after figuring out form the docs that e_axis has an index argument. As I mentioned in my answer I  struggle with the docs of `echarts4r` or `echarts` too. Same with `plotly` or `highcharter`. While all offer a lot of options and arguments it's not always clear to me what they are doing and which one to use to achieve a desired result.